# Where should I use Configuration or LoggerConfig in log4j?

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

[image: UML Diagram]

This is UML class diagram of `Log4j` main core classes.

There is a `Configuration` which has an one to one relation with `LoggerContext`.

Also there is a `LoggerConfig` which every `Logger` instance should contain one (but may share)

And `Configuration` has an aggregation relation with `LoggerConfig` that means each `Configuration` contains instances of `LoggerConfig`

Both Configuration and LoggerConfig have `Filter`s and `Appender`s

So my question is when should I use each class and what are use cases each one fit in.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be that you use neither. The UML diagram shows a few key classes used by Log4j2 *under the hood*. In your application it's better not to use any of these implementation classes and instead only use the classes in the log4j-api module.

Unless your application needs to be configured programmatically for some reason, I would recommend you keep your logging configuration separated from your application code. By default Log4j2 will look for a configuration file named log4j2.xml in the classpath. Other formats like .properties, .json, and .yaml are also supported.

In your application you usually only need the Logger and the LogManager classes from the API module.